# CollectionView.Header bug in MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

I have a problem with *CollectionView.Header* in .NET MAUI. I don't know if that is a MAUI bug.
I also asked for help here: [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1611645/net-maui-collectionview-problems?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1476071#newest-answer-comment), but nothing helped so far.

```xml
<CollectionView
    Grid.Row="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListProducts}">
    <CollectionView.Header>
        <Grid
            Padding="0,0,0,0"
            ColumnSpacing="0"
            BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Culture}"
            HeightRequest="40">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Referencia"
                Style="{DynamicResource TextCaptionSemibold}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="8,0,0,0"/>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="Nombre"
                Style="{DynamicResource TextCaptionSemibold}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="2"
                Text=""/>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="3"
                Text=""/>

        </Grid>
    </CollectionView.Header>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            x:DataType="model:LineProductCatalogDTO">

            <Grid
                Padding="0,0,0,0"
                ColumnSpacing="0"
                HeightRequest="64">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <BoxView
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    HeightRequest="1"
                    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray2}"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                <Label
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Text="{Binding Reference}" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Style="{DynamicResource TextBodyRegular}"
                    Margin="8,0,0,0"/>

                <Label
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Style="{DynamicResource TextBodyRegular}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

                <ButtonIconStandard:ButtonIconStandard
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    Icon="ic_info_primary.png"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Margin="0,0,8,0"
                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ProductDetailCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=dashboardPage}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsProductDetailButtonVisible, Source={x:Reference Name=containerTableProductListOutputView}}"/>

                <ButtonIconPrimary:ButtonIconPrimary
                    Grid.Column="3" 
                    Icon="ic_add_white.png"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Margin="0,0,8,0"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsAddProductButtonVisible, Source={x:Reference Name=containerTableProductListOutputView}}"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

result:
[image: app printscreen]

You can see that *CollectionView.Header* background color isn't responsive and that colunm Name isn't align with your value. I don't know how to resolve that.

Responsive result:
[image: printscreen]

I tried that on *CollectionView.ItemTemplate* and *CollectionView.Header*:

```xml
<ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
```

but it didn't change anything.
Can you help me?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21179

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT The OP reported that issue. It makes more sense to add it directly to the question.